# Network issues on Windows 10 PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a WiFi network at home and I have issue with PC. My laptop and phone connection is okay (Speed is 20mbps (download), which it should be), but PC have two issues with speed (download from 100kbps to 2mbps) and stability.
Main issue is stability, because sometimes it disconnects and ping is about 1000-20000 ms (but at the same time connection on laptop is okay).
So after trying some solutions I found on google I connected my PC and laptop via Ethernet and the first time it worked perfectly. But some days after some lags appeared again (PC's `ping` says there is no connection, but laptop's `ping` is okay). I thought it was WiFi problem. But since these lags appear randomly I can't figure out which part software/hardware is a problem.

My question is - What checks should I do to clear out what is the problem? I'd like not only solve current problem, I want to know what to do if I will have another network issues next time. So, some good articles or book (better it would be a chapter, I'm not about to deep in networks) will be also appreciated.

P.S.
Upload speed is 4mpbs for everything: PC, laptop and phone. So problem is around downloading.

Comment: There is so much to consider with WiFi communications. It would be very difficult to provide you anything comprehensive. Have you checked the obvious things, like signal strength, distance, interference?

Comment: Router is close really close, no interference. Signal (wifi icon on tray) is good.

Comment: You should try to install the latest driver for the WiFi adapter and the latest firmware for your WiFi router. You didn’t mention if this is 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz band? My best suggestion is that you upgrade equipment as necessary to make sure everything is running at 5Ghz. I can’t use 2.4Ghz at my house because there are too many people using it nearby. I can’t even sit right next to the router and use it. 5Ghz works great. And some hardware handles that better or worse. You need to try to adjust channels on your router so that you are on as clean of a frequency as possible.

Comment: I disabled 5ghz on the router because of... I dont remeber what issue was, ISP said that it is better to use 2.4ghz only. Ok, I'll try. Thanks.